# Scrollbar Value is not changing from c# script (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollbar

I have created 1 scroll view in my scene. I am setting scrollbar value from c# script, but by default always it set to 0.5. I've researched for the same form this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/865387/view.html). Also, I am copying snippet for the same i've used.

```
    float ScrollBarValue = 0.001f;
    int SelectCharacterNumber = TheGameController.instance.GetSelectedCharacter ();

    if (SelectCharacterNumber <= 5) {
        ScrollBarValue = 0.001f;
    } else if (SelectCharacterNumber <= 10) {
        ScrollBarValue = 0.5f;
    } else if (SelectCharacterNumber > 10) {
        ScrollBarValue = 1f;
    }

    HorizontalScrollbar.GetComponent<Scrollbar> ().value = ScrollBarValue;
```

What should I correct in this?

Comment: where is this code snippet placed?

Comment: it is done. problem was with script. script sets the scrollbar value at start, where as I need the scrollbar value when panel gets open. So I've placed the above code in a function from where panel gets open.